# Unable to bring up docker project

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm following [this Docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database), which creates a simple Docker-managed Django site, and when I try to run `docker-compose up` to launch my docker project, I get the ambiguous error:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?
```

The error suggests that the Docker daemon isn't running, but `service docker status` shows the Docker daemon is running.

If instead I run `sudo docker-compose up`, then it succeeds, but it chowns a lot of my local development files to the root user, which is easy enough to fix, but annoying.

Why does Docker require root access just to start a local Django development server? How do I fix this?

My versions:

```
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
```

Comment: Have you tried making your own user a member of the `docker` group? https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 0):

If you can run any Docker command at all, you can trivially root the host:

```
docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox \
  cat /host/etc/shadow
```

Additionally, Docker containers frequently run as root within their own container space, which means that whatever parts of the host filesystem you choose to expose into them, they can make arbitrary changes as arbitrary user IDs.  You can use a `docker run -u` option to pick a different user ID, but you can pick *any* user ID, even one that belongs to another user on a shared system.

It is very reasonable to use `sudo` as a way to get root privileges for things that need it, and this is a typical out-of-the-box Docker configuration.

At the end of the day the only real gate on this is the Unix permissions on the file `/var/run/docker.sock`.  This is often mode 0660 owned by a dedicated `docker` group.  If you don’t mind your normal user being able to read and write arbitrary host files without much of a control at all, you can add yourself to that group.  That’s frequently appropriate for something like a developer laptop; but on anything like a production system it deserves some real consideration of its security implications.